# intercommunication among classes in java

Tags: java, game-engine

Please forgive my lousy terminology!

I've been struggling with a problem for some time now.

I'm making a game-engine in java where I constantly encounter the same problem. I've got this class hierarchy:

PARENT -> CHILD -> GRANDCHILD

where PARENT owns and constructs CHILD and so forth.

Now, the parent has the ability to do stuff that both CHILD and GRANDCHILD needs to do during execution. Lets say that GRANDCHILD is a button in the GUI and PARENT is the CORE of the game. If the button is pushed I want to pause the game. The button/GRANDCHILD has no means of doing this itself, but needs to do it through the PARENT/CORE.

PARENT            --> CHILD          --> GRANDCHILD 
+pause game()        + do something()

I've got three solutions to this problem, none which satisfies me.

1. Return values. PARENT/GAME-CORE feels that the mouse has been pressed, calls CHILD, which calls GRANDCHILD. GRANDCHILD acknowledges that it's been pressed and returns an int, or enum to the PARENT/CORE. The PARENT/CORE uses and case/if-else to determine what needs to be done.

PARENT int:click()--> CHILD int:click() --> GRANCHILD int:click()

PARENT'S function

```
switch(CHILD.click(){
case 1 do this;
case 2: do that;
etc.
}
```

This is the solution that I hate the most. Not only do I need to keep track of ints /enums, but I also need to use switch/if-else when I could use polymorphism to get cleaner code.

2. I think this method is called call-back. Upon construction PARENT sends an inner class/a bundle of functions, which is passed down to the constructor of the GRANDCHILD. The GRANDCHILD saves this inner class instance and invokes its methods when it needs to.

   class PARENT{

   CHILD child;

   PARENT(){
   child = new CHILD(new Controller);
   }

   class Controller{

   public void click(){
   do stuff...
   }

   }

   }

This is ok, but doesn't feel right. The gamecore might have hundreds of CHILDREN and that means hundred of inner classes, which functions might do more or less the same thing. Classes will become huge when as the game grows. This also creates cycles in the hierarchy, and I have a feeling that's bad.

3. I think this is called "services". PARENT/GAMECORE is public. Any class can invoke its methods. Well, in the case: PARENT->CHILD->GRANDCHILD, both PARENT and CHILD needs to be public, since GRANDCHILD needs both CHILD's methods and PARENTS. This doesn't feel too good.

I could live with this if there only was a handful of classes that needed to be accessible. Problem is that I need intercommunication all the time, by everyone, almost!

So what can I do? Have I missed something, and if not, what of the above is the best practise and will save me from future headaches?

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on your coding style.
If you take a look into some game libraries, often, the main core objects (your core, input, whatever) can be called from anywhere in your code, using singletons or other patterns.

If you use Java 1.8, you could use your callback feature without having to write a lot of inner classes.

```
//in your child/grandchild
public void doStuff(Runnable callback){
    //do stuff
    callback.run();
}
```

And you can pass [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to these Methods

```
//somewhere else
child.doStuff(core::myCallbackFunction);
```

You can pass a lot of different consumer/supplier/functions this way using the functional interfaces, so you can also write callbacks with parameters and return values.

But, mostly, it depends on what you feel is the best/most comfortable coding style for you.

Comment: So there's no great technique that I've missed, which can release me from my anguish?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Another possible way could be to pass some kind of core object through methods, and this core object contains `public` children of other core objects. So you'd get rid of singletons. `public void update(Core c){c.Input.getInput();...}`

Answer (score 0):

One thing about your post that is slightly confusing is that the 'parent' and 'children' here are not actually parent and children in the object-oriented sense, but merely interacting objects. As such, any specific functionality should be handled by a relevant class only - there is no need to involve other objects in passing the message back and forth.

For GUI elements, like buttons, consider using listeners. Make the core implement a suitable Listener interface and add that to each of the elements - this is the Observer design pattern, and is somewhat similar to the callback approach.

Comment: It's true, the PARENT -> CHILD -> GRANDCHILD is still the view in my example, but they are related in that sense in other ways I haven't mentioned. However, the problem stands that PARENT, CHILD, GRANDCHILD all needs access to the "model" and the model in turn needs some access to the view (the gui). I'm confused myself, but thanks for the tip!.